# Comment character in datatool AND ignore empty lines?

Tags: datatool

Here is a minimal example on using the `datatool` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

    {\DTLsettabseparator%
    \DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={T,R}]{data}{data.csv}}% Brackets necessary in conjunction with some other packages that don't like what DLTsettabseparator does

    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \DTLforeach{data}{\first=T,\last=R}{ $\first\ K$ & $\last\ k\Omega$ \\ }
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`data.csv`:

```
# This is 'data.csv'
# I'd like comments like this to be ignored by datatool

# And empty lines as well!

# Now comes the data
# Format:
# T[K]    R[kΩ]
1.4 12.79
8.1 8.81
11.4 8.24
17.3 6.63
25.7 5.27
31.2 3.58
39.0 3.03
44.3 2.38
54.7 1.72
61.2 1.21
69.7 0.987
81.0 0.718
88.5 0.626
99.6 0.491
```

Is there a way to suppress output of lines that start with a `#` and also suppress the output of empty lines? Or even define a comment character?

**Edit:**
Added a sample `.csv` file.

Comment: We could do with a minimal example `.csv` file

Comment: I checked the [RFC4180](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) which defines the `csv` format and unfortunately neither comments nor empty lines are supported (the `csv` ABNF grammar can give you more information on this). In this case, the format you want to use extends the original `csv` definition, so it's probably beyond the scope of the `datatool` package. IMHO the solution might be implementing a custom parser with both comments and empty lines rules defined. `:)`

Comment: I've lodged a feature request with Nicola Talbot on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get `datatool` to handle this, but `pgfplotstable`, which has similar functionality, ignores comment lines and empty lines out of the box. The following code will typeset a simple table of your data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
# This is 'data.csv'
# I'd like comments like this to be ignored by datatool

# And empty lines as well!

# Now comes the data
# Format:
# T[K]    R[kΩ]
1.4 12.79
8.1 8.81
11.4 8.24
17.3 6.63
25.7 5.27
31.2 3.58
39.0 3.03
44.3 2.38
54.7 1.72
61.2 1.21
69.7 0.987
81.0 0.718
88.5 0.626
99.6 0.491
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{testdata.csv}\testdata
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testdata}
\end{document}
```

---

I thought you might be interested in what else you can do with this data in LaTeX. Below is an example where I use `pgfplotstable` to typeset the results in a prettier way, using the lines provided by `booktabs`. I also plot the data using `pgfplots`, and fit an exponential function using `gnuplot`. The fit parameters are displayed on the plot. All of this is done using a single TeX file and a single compilation run. If your data changes, the table, graph and fit parameters will all automatically reflect the changes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   % For plotting
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}  % For typesetting units in plot
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For typesetting tables from data
\usepackage{siunitx} % For typesetting units
\usepackage{booktabs} % Nicer horziontal lines and corresponding spacing
\usepackage{filecontents} % To include the data file in this .tex file
\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
# This is 'data.csv'
# I'd like comments like this to be ignored by datatool

# And empty lines as well!

# Now comes the data
# Format:
# T[K]    R[kΩ]
1.4 12.79
8.1 8.81
11.4 8.24
17.3 6.63
25.7 5.27
31.2 3.58
39.0 3.03
44.3 2.38
54.7 1.72
61.2 1.21
69.7 0.987
81.0 0.718
88.5 0.626
99.6 0.491
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{testdata.csv}\testdata % Read data file into a table macro
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    fixed zerofill, % Print numbers in fixed format, add zeros if necessary
    dec sep align, % Align numbers at the decimal point
    columns/0/.style={ % Options for the first column
        precision=1, % One decimal
        column name={
            \shortstack{$T$\\\si{\kelvin}} % Define column name. Use \shortstack to get two lines
        }
    },
    columns/1/.style={
        column name={
            \shortstack{$R$\\\si{\kilo\ohm}}
        }
    },
    every head row/.style={ % Set style for title row
        before row=\toprule, % Rules from booktabs package
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={ % Set style for final row
        after row=\bottomrule
    }
]{\testdata}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline] % "baseline" for correct vertical alignment with the table
\begin{axis}[
    anchor=center, % For correct vertical alignment with the table
    ymin=0, enlarge y limits=upper, % Fix lower y limit at zero, increase upper limit a bit
    xmin=0,xmax=100, % Fix lower and upper limits for x
    axis lines*=left, % Axis lines without arrow tips at the left and bottom
    unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}, % Use siunitx for typesetting units
    xlabel=$T$, x unit=\kelvin, % Set labels and units
    ylabel=$R$, y unit=\kilo\ohm, ylabel style={rotate=-90}] % Typeset y label horizontally
\addplot [black, only marks] table \testdata; % Add the data points from the table
\addplot+[raw gnuplot, draw=red, no markers, smooth] gnuplot { % Issue gnuplot command, plot as smoothed line
    f(x)=a*exp(b*x); % Define function to fit
    a=15; % Initial values
    b=-1;
    fit f(x) 'testdata.csv' using 1:2 via a,b; % Perform fit
    plot [x=0:100] f(x); % calculate points for curve
    set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into
    print a,b; % Write the parameters to file
};
\pgfplotsextra{ % Execute code at end of plot, when everything else has been run
    \pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters % Open the file Gnuplot wrote
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramA{\pgfplotsretval} % Get first element, save into \paramA
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramB{\pgfplotsretval}
    \node at (axis cs:5,10) [ % Position a node at the logical coordinate (4,10)
        pin=5:$\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\paramB}\cdot T}$] {}; % Typeset equation using the `pin` argument.
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. I thank you kindly for the work you put into this! I really appreciate the beatufull answer. As plotting goes I've pretty much settled with gnuplot. Not going to switch as I'm very comfortable with it. I just wanted a way typeset tables from my gnuplot data files automatically, i.e. without copying the data into the latex file manually.

Comment: I would like to know if something is possible or not. If I have a `.csv` file and I need to place a  comment inside a cell entry, how can it be done? For example, I have a cell of `21`, and I need to write some comment (e.g. `21 <my comment>`  ) inside this cell of `csv` file without being rendered by `pgfplotstable`, so the output is still `21`. Is it possible? If possible, I would be happy if you could answer [my similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344496/2288) of `datatool` but with `pgfplotstable` approach.