# datatool: How to comment inside cell entry?

Tags: comments, datatool

In this MWE, I need to suppress the output of comment written inside the cell entry. In other words, I need to make a placeholder for comments inside cells of my interest.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.csv}
1 (comment to suppress) , 2 (another comment to suppress)
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{db}{sample.csv}

\begin{document}
    \DTLgetvalue{\firstvalue}{db}{1}{1}
    \DTLgetvalue{\secondvalue}{db}{1}{2}
    \firstvalue and \secondvalue
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are all the comments of the form `<space>(<text>)`?

Comment: @egreg It doesn't matter, I just need any opening and closing symbols to be recognized by `datatool` as a placeholder for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your comments are of the form `(<text>)`, you can do like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
1 (comment to suppress), 2 (another comment to suppress), 3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\decomment}[1]{%
  \expandafter\de@comment#1()\@nil{#1}%
}
\def\de@comment#1(#2)#3\@nil#4{%
  \def#4{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{db}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLgetvalue{\firstvalue}{db}{1}{1}
\DTLgetvalue{\secondvalue}{db}{1}{2}
\DTLgetvalue{\thirdvalue}{db}{1}{3}

\decomment{\firstvalue}\decomment{\secondvalue}\decomment{\thirdvalue}

\firstvalue{} and \secondvalue{} and \thirdvalue{}

\end{document}
```

Curiously enough, the first entry becomes `1(comment to suppress)`, so the space cannot be safely removed this way, without a more complex check.

An easier method is with `l3regex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
1 (comment to suppress), 2 (another comment to suppress), 3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\decomment}{m}
 {
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \s*\(.*\)\s*\Z } { } #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{db}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLgetvalue{\firstvalue}{db}{1}{1}
\DTLgetvalue{\secondvalue}{db}{1}{2}
\DTLgetvalue{\thirdvalue}{db}{1}{3}

\decomment{\firstvalue}\decomment{\secondvalue}\decomment{\thirdvalue}

\firstvalue{} and \secondvalue{} and \thirdvalue{}

\end{document}
```

The regular expression is “any number of spaces followed by `(`, by arbitrary tokens, by `)`, by spaces and the end of the token list”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it and get back to you in case I need some tweaks. Off-topic question: what is the difference between storing data in `\jobname.csv` and `sample.csv`? is it better to take a macro form?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I changed the file name in order not to possibly clobber already existing files as I always do with `filecontents`. Just a personal precaution, not mandatory for you.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Regarding your answer, if I want to generalize the comment delimiters (e.g. using `#...#` or `<<...>>`), is it easy to hack your second code of `l3regex`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Well, `#` is always problematic in TeX; for `<<...>>` just use `\s*<<.*>>\s*\Z`

Comment: I found the same output for both `\s*<<.*>>\Z` and `\s*<<.*>>\s*\Z`, could you please tell me the meaning of `\s*` and the reason why there was no effect when removed?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou That removes also trailing spaces (I don't really know whether `datatool` does to begin with).

Comment: I appreciate your consideration.