# How to define comment delimiters of a table cell?

Tags: tables

I would like to extend my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/344496/2288) and know how to type a comment, using delimiters, in any table cell to be suppressed in the compiled PDF without the need to use, for example, `\iffalse...\fi`.

For instance, here, the comment delimiters are `<<` and `>>`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline 
    1st entry <<1st comment>> & 2nd entry <<2nd comment>>  \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Moriambar It is pretty close to what I need. However, is there a way to parse `<<` and `>>` as comment delimiters. It is easier to handle without the need to define commands, especially in large tables.

Comment: why use special syntax rather than `\comment{1st comment}` which can trivially be defined as `\newcommand\comment[1]{}` ? Or why not use standard TeX comment `%`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I think I exaggerated a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend the following solution at all, since you will not be able to use the less-than character after that as usual any more.

After the lines

```
\catcode`<=\active
\def<<#1>>{}
```

you will be able to mark comments using `<<...>>`. But this may have undesirable consequences if you need `<` in any other context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and get back in case I find any problems.